# Spring Boot - Unable to get response of Keycloak authorized api via Zuul proxy

Tags: spring-boot, docker, keycloak, netflix-zuul

I using spring boot microservices and docker for my application. I have expose all endpoint via Zuul proxy. And also I have used keycloak to secure my api endpoints. Which I configured in `application.properties` file as show in bellow. Currently I am unable to get the response of my microservice's api which is authorized using `keycloak.securityConstraints`.

Please note that I have also change subnet and gateway of docker0 to `169.254.0.1/24` and `169.254.0.1`. Please find following files of my application.

**docker-compose.yml** without specify a subnet

```
version: "3"
services:
    eureka-naming-server:
        image: eureka-naming-server
        ports:
            - "8761:8761"
        container_name: eureka-naming-server
    zuul-proxy-service:
        image: zuul-proxy-service
        ports:
            - "8765:8765"
        links:
            - eureka-naming-server
        container_name: zuul-proxy-service
    user-service:
        image: user-service
        ports:
            - "8082:8082"
        links:
            - eureka-naming-server
        container_name: user-service
    keycloak:
        image: jboss/keycloak
        container_name: keycloak
        environment:
            KEYCLOAK_USER: user
            KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: user_password
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
```

**docker-compose.yml** with a specify default subnet

```
version: "3"
services:
    eureka-naming-server:
        image: eureka-naming-server
        ports:
            - "8761:8761"
        container_name: eureka-naming-server
    zuul-proxy-service:
        image: zuul-proxy-service
        ports:
            - "8765:8765"
        links:
            - eureka-naming-server
        container_name: zuul-proxy-service
    user-service:
        image: user-service
        ports:
            - "8082:8082"
        links:
            - eureka-naming-server
        container_name: user-service
    keycloak:
        image: jboss/keycloak
        container_name: keycloak
        environment:
            KEYCLOAK_USER: user
            KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: user_password
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
networks:
    default:
        ipam:
            config:
                - subnet: "169.254.3.0/24"
```

**application.yml** of Zull proxy

```
server:
  port: 8765

eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://eureka-naming-server:8761/eureka/
  instance:
    prefer-ip-address: true
    metadataMap:
      instanceId: ${vcap.application.instance_id:${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}}
    instanceId: ${vcap.application.instance_id:${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}}

zuul:
  prefix: /api
  sensitive-headers:
  add-proxy-headers: false
  routes:
    user-service:
      path: /user/**
      service-id: USER-SERVICE
```

**application.yml** of user-service

```
spring.application.name=user-service
keycloak.realm=master
keycloak.resource=my-client
keycloak.auth-server-url=http://<ip>/auth
keycloak.public-client=true
keycloak.principal-attribute=preferred_username
keycloak.securityConstraints[0].authRoles[0]=admin
keycloak.securityConstraints[0].securityCollections[0].patterns[0]=/change-password
```

**Here is my problem**

**1)** When I am not using zuul proxy (i.e. **http//:8082/change-password**) i can successfully get response using valid keycloak token. But when using **http//:8765/api/user/change-password** and **docker-compose.yml with a specify default subnet** i can not get the responce.

I always get following responce headers with 200 status for a valid token.

```
 cache-control: private 
 date: Wed, 21 Aug 2019 11:02:02 GMT 
 expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT 
 transfer-encoding: chunked
```

And following log created in user-service logs.

```
2019-08-21 03:18:26.191  WARN [-,,,] 1 --- [nio-8087-exec-2] o.k.adapters.RequestAuthenticator        : SSL is required to authenticate. Remote address 169.254.0.4 is secure: false, SSL required for: EXTERNAL .
```

However when i used invalid token i am getting 401 error (As expected).

Do i need to use a route filter for this issue???

Any help would be grateful !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears that SSL is required for all external requests. This can be set e.g. via the admin console in `Realm Settings -> Login -> Require SSL` (https://www.keycloak.org/docs/5.0/server_admin/index.html#_ssl_modes).
For testing purposes, you can try and set it to `None`. Never do this on a production system.

The same thing can be done for the client (in `application.yml` of the user-service):

```
keycloak.ssl-required = none
```

(https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_java_adapter_config)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. Setting via admin console not worked. I am currently using keycloak version 5.0. Can you please explain a bit about your last suggestion.

Comment: Did you receive the same error? This should also work identical for version 5 - I updated my answer.

Comment: After setting `PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING` to `true` i am getting `Failed to fetch` error. Furthermore i am getting (http://169.254.3.6:8082/change-password) as **Request URL** in swagger. `169.254.3.6` is ip4 address of default network which create from docker-compose

Comment: OK, sorry I got it wrong. Your Keycloak is not behind a proxy right? So what happens if you set Require SSL to None? Any other error?

Comment: No. I am getting same error. which i have mentioned above.

Comment: Try setting `keycloak.ssl-required` for your user-service.

Comment: Thank you. It has worked. But I am getting internal server error (500) time to time

Answer (score 2):

I also run into this issue when using a reverse proxy with microservices behind the proxy that have keyloak integration. The reason for the error is some kind of security implementation from keycloak that checks the X-Forward headers provided by the reverse proxy. It is explained it detail in the [documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/index.html#identifying-client-ip-addresses), but to be honest I did not really understand why it is required. So an easy solution to get rid of this error is to simply discard the X-Forward headers, which makes the request look like an internal request.

In Zuul:

```
zuul:
  add-proxy-headers: false
```

In Spring Cloud Gateway:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      x-forwarded:
        port-enabled: false
        host-enabled: false
        proto-enabled: false
        port-append: false
        host-append: false
        proto-append: false
        enabled: false
```

Setting `keycloak.ssl-required` on every microservice behind the reverse proxy could probably also work, but I did not try it. I prefer to have the config in one place only.

Answer (score 0):

- linux
- Spring boot
- keycloak
- java-docker

When developing locally, we encountered a similar problem, but since we couldn’t find a suitable solution on the Internet, we decided to share our solution here with our colleagues.

It was decided to run the Spring application being developed not on java installed locally on the system, but on a container located in Docker.
The application starts, but during HTTP requests it crashes with the keycloak error:

> SSL is required to authenticate. Remote address IP is secure: false,
> SSL required for: EXTERNAL .

Analyzing the situation, **org.keycloak.adapters.RequestAuthenticator** and **org.keycloak.common.enums.SslRequired** were analyzed.

Implementations of these classes check whether **IP** is a local address of the site and, as it turned out, the subnet address in which the docker container was launched with java was not local according to the keycloak implementation.

Changing the docker daemon config solved this problem:

**/etc/docker/daemon.json**

```
{
  "default-address-pools":
  [
    {"base":"172.18.0.0/16","size":24}
  ]
}
```

> sudo systemctl restart docker